# Showing Total saving amount in Magento checkout

Tags: php, magento, e-commerce, checkout

I need to show the total saving amount in the magento checkout page.
What i mean is :

You save : XXX $
Where xxx is ( sum of total regular prices of products in the cart ) - ( Sum of total special prices of products in the cart ).

Thx for your help guys

Answer (score 0):

```
 <?php
    $cart = Mage::getModel('checkout/cart')->getQuote();    
    foreach ($cart->getAllItems() as $item) {      
        $productPrice = $item->getProduct()->getPrice();
        //echo $productPrice."<br />";
        $pp[] = $productPrice;
    }
    $totalprice = array_sum($pp);
    $grandTotal = Mage::getModel('checkout/cart')->getQuote()->getGrandTotal();
    $flagValue = $totalprice - $grandTotal;    
    if ($flagValue > 0) { ?>
        <p class="flagValue">You are saving <b>&pound;<?php echo $flagValue; ?></b> today.</p><?php } ?>
```

It will work

Thanks
Yogesh Dubey

Answer (score 0):

I know this is too late for reply, i have the same requirement in magento which is i am currently working on.i have search in google and found this link but unfortunately the above code is not working so i have decided to build my own, now its working like a charm for me...

Here is the code

```
<?php
    $sOrderId = Mage::getSingleton('checkout/session')->getLastOrderId();
    $oOrder = Mage::getModel('sales/order')->load($sOrderId);
    $obj = Mage::getModel('catalog/product');
    $oOrder->getGrandTotal()."</br></br>";
    $order = Mage::getSingleton('sales/order'); 
    $order->loadByIncrementId(Mage::getSingleton('checkout/session')->getLastRealOrderId());
    $_items = $order->getAllItems();
    $n=count($_items)."</br>";
    for($i=0;$i<$n;$i++){
        //$cost_id[] = $_items[$i]['product_id'];
        $_product = $obj->load($_items[$i]['product_id']);
        $cost_id[] = $_product->getPrice()."</br>";
    }
    $totalprice = array_sum($cost_id);
    $disc_price = $totalprice - $oOrder->getGrandTotal();
    echo "You have saved ".$disc_price." today";
    ?>
```

Hope it will helps anyone

Thank you